# How to make browser ignore cached data and reload it

Tags: javascript, caching, browser-cache

I am trying to execute last modified JavaScript after i change it, however, browsers insist on using cached data. I use shift+f5 to override cached data and download fresh copy from the server. It works for this case.

Lets assume that i launched the site and its used constantly.

After i change a JavaScript file. None of the user will not be able to see the changes (for who entered the site before the change). So, how can i force all clients to erase or ignore current cached data and download all the site.

I found a workaround. If i change the file name, browser downloads it. Which is not surprising. Is there any other solution (preferably more professional) to make browser ignore cached data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let say your file is `<script src  = "javascript-code.js"></script>`, if you edit it and would like the have it automatically reload on all the other client browsers you can rename it `<script src  = "javascript-code.js?rnd=123"></script>`. Changing the value in the query string will force the browsers which cached the JS to get a fresh copy from the server.

Comment: should i change rnd everytime i change the file?

Comment: You cannot control the client browser cache. If the browser has cashed the JS, the only way would be to fool the browser into thinking that it needs to reload the file. Adding a meaningless query string at the end can do the trick. And yes every time you make a change you should give a different value to ?rnd=<your value goes here>